# Using ESP_NOW with loop and delays

Tags: c++, loops, delay, esp32, arduino-ide

I'm trying to receive a data from one *esp32* to another.
I'm also doing some `looping` with `delays` for reading a sensor data and switch on/off relay *cooling*.
This device also use `ESPAsyncWebServer` as API server (not included in code for the size).
I'm receiving the data from one *eps32* in `POST` request to API right now. I would like to change this as to be able to recieve with `esp_now`. I was doing some experiments, but the *data receving* is delayed because of `delay` method in loop.
Is there a way to make this *asynchronized* as for example the `ESPA` above?

I also tried a way with comparing a `milis()` (time) to wait for a loop, but I thing that is too "resource consuming" task, to let it compare in full speed in loop like a vortex forever.

here is my loop
it's just a simple loop with some vars and delay function for example

```cpp
void loop() {
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
        float temp_check = dht.readTemperature();

        if (temp_check == 0) {
            delay(1000);
            temp_check = dht.readTemperature();
        }

        if (temp_check > 32.0 && *cooling_switch_p == false) {
            Serial.println("[ INF ] Too high temperature, switch on a cooling system");
            digitalWrite(COOLING_RELAY, LOW);
            *cooling_switch_p = true;
        }
        else if (temp_check < 30.0  && *cooling_switch_p == true) {
            Serial.println("[ INF ] Normal temperature, switch off a cooling system");
            digitalWrite(COOLING_RELAY, HIGH);
            *cooling_switch_p = false;
        }

        Serial.print("[ DBG ] Light Switch: ");
        Serial.println(String(light_switch));
        Serial.println("");

        Serial.print("[ DBG ] Pump Switch: ");
        Serial.println(String(pump_switch));
        Serial.println("");
        delay(5000);
    }

    else {
        Serial.println("[ ERR ] Wifi not connected. Exiting program");
        delay(9999);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to *send* your sensor data from this device to another one while more or less accurately maintaining the 5-second sampling interval. You can create a simple asynchronous architecture yourself using 2 threads.

The existing thread (created by Arduino) runs your current `loop()` which reads the sensor every 5 seconds. You add a second thread which deals with transmitting the sample to other devices. The first thread posts the sample to the second thread through a FreeRTOS queue; second thread immediately goes to work transmitting. The first thread continues to mind its own business without waiting for transmission to complete.

Using the FreeRTOS documentation on creating [tasks](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) and [queues](https://www.freertos.org/a00116.html):

```
#include <task.h>
#include <queue.h>
#include <assert.h>

TaskHandle_t hTxTask;
QueueHandle_t hTxQueue;

constexpr size_t TX_QUEUE_LEN = 10;

// The task which transmits temperature samples to wherever needed
void txTask(void* parm) {
  while (true) {
    float temp;
    // Block until a sample is posted to queue
    const BaseType_t res = xQueueReceive(hTxQueue, static_cast<void*>(&temp), portMAX_DELAY);
    assert(res);
    // Here you write your code to send the temperature to other device
    // e.g.: esp_now_send(temp);
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Create the queue
  hTxQueue = xQueueCreate(TX_QUEUE_LEN, sizeof(float));
  assert(hTxQueue);
  // Create and start the TX task
  const BaseType_t res = xTaskCreate(txTask, "TX task", 8192, nullptr, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &hTxTask);
  assert(res);
  // ... rest of your setup()
}

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    float temp_check = dht.readTemperature();
    // Post fresh sample to queue
    const BaseType_t res = xQueueSendToBack(hTxQueue, &temp_check, 0);
    if (!res) {
      Serial.println("Error: TX queue full!");
    }
    // ... Rest of your loop code
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to not "send", but "receive" with this device, but I think the code you provided will works in that way also!

Comment: OK, have fun then!